# Sonicwall SNMP configuration

Tags: firewall, snmp, snmpwalk

I'm playing with an old Sonicwall and I'd like to configure it with SNMP. All docs and Googling I've done show the same procedure:

- System > Administration > SNMP Enabled ( community string etc. )
- Networking > Interfaces, check SNMP box

But when I do `snmpwalk` (from Linux box) I just get Timeout.

There's no iptables on the box. Any hints ?

Comment: Do you have a bridged WAN>LAN interface? If so, both interfaces need SNMP enabled.  Do you have the PC you're testing from added as a host under System>Administration>SNMP? Could you post your `snmpwalk` command and/or a screen shot of your config?

Comment: Hi Josh, yes i have check on both interfaces the SNMP. Yes i have the PC listed in System>Administration>SNMP as Hosts1,2,3 etc. And the snmpwalk is: 'snmpwalk -v 2c -c Public x.x.x.x -m ALL' and the results is: "Timeout: No Response from x.x.x.x". I have also try with the backup line we have as HA we use and local ip as we have VPN. Still nothing.

Comment: I have use mibbrowser on the local subnet (Sonicwall site) and it works perfect. From the same machine i try to get info on the linux box and again works perfect. So im guessing no Firewall rule is get on the way. Seems like im doing something wrong on the Linux Box. Do i have to change something in the snmpd.conf file ? should i add some kind of community or something for version 2. ?